# WPF event unsubscribe leak in DataTemplate (XAML) on NET Framework

Tags: wpf, xaml

Imagine a `UserControl` with a `ListBox` having a `CheckBox` in a `DataTemplate`. The `ItemsSource` for the `ListBox` is some global list. The `CheckBox` has `Checked/Unchecked` events attached to it.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static a:MainWindow.Source}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type a:Data}">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                      Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"
                      Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"
                      Padding="10"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I am logging loaded/unloaded/checked/unchecked events in the main window's log.

```
    private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Checked");
    }

    private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Unchecked");
    }

    private void UserControl1_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Loaded");
    }

    private void UserControl1_OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("Unloaded");
    }
```

The main window features a dynamic list of `UserControl1` instances (starting with just one). There are add/remove buttons that allow me to add more instances.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="2">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Add">Add</Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Remove">Remove</Button>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This,Path=Log}" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

The window's codebehind:

```
    private void Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox.Items.Add(new UserControl1());
    }

    private void Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox.Items.Count == 0) return;
        ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

When I run the app there is just one `UserControl1` instance. If I add one more and then immediately remove one of them, then click the one and only checkbox on the screen, I see two "Checked" events logged. If I now uncheck it, there are two "Unchecked" events (even though "Unloaded" event was previously clearly logged. The hex numbers on the left show the output of a `GetHashCode()` which clearly shows the events were handled by distinct `UserControl1` instances.

[image]

So even though one of `UserControl1` gets unloaded, the events don't seem to get unsubscribed automatically. I have tried upgrading to NET Framework 4.8 to no avail. I see the same behavior. If I add 10 new controls and remove them immediately, I will observe 10 "Checked" or "Unchecked" events.

I have tried searching for a similar problem but could not find it. Is there something I am missing or did I just encounter a bug? Looking for workarounds.

Full source code is available on GitHub. https://github.com/wpfwannabe/datacontext-event-leak

Comment: Have you tried to force garbage collection after `ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);` ? My understanding is that WPF use weak events and they are unregistred at GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *MVVM* pattern, the view is bind to the view model and doesn't survive it when the garbage collection do it's job.

In the example you provided, the view model is a static object and by definition can't be garbage collected, so the view can't neither be garbage collected.

There is no automatic *unbinding* since you can reuse an instance of an user control (it can be `Loaded` and `UnLoaded` multiple times).

The simplest¹ way to fix this memory leak is to do the *unbinding* on *unload* :

### Wpf

```
// First give the ListBox a name
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static a:MainWindow.Source}}">
```

### Code behind

```
private void UserControl1_OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Log("Unloaded");
    ListBox.ItemsSource = null;
}
```

1: The proper way is to wrap the static list in a dedicated list view model, make the view model disposable (to unbind the wrapper from the static list on dispose), dispose the view model on remove.

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you. I have come to the same solution minutes after posting the answer. The one thing I slightly disagree with you upon is that WPF should really (regardless of whether one uses MVVM or not) unsubscribe any events that were previously subscribed to. When a `ListBoxItem` is created and `DataTemplate` applied, the "unload" event of the `ListBoxItem` should really contain some sort of tear-down logic. Either way, I am happy there is a workaround.

Comment: @wpfwannabe take a look at the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded?view=windowsdesktop-5.0 loaded/unloaded events are indeed disappointing and I don't really on them for subscription/unsubscription